# User do not receive notification in my android app

Tags: java, android, facebook, notifications

I developed an app, and Need to invite your friends in the game.
I send the request through the app-to-user's way
But confusing.
users who is not using the app can not receive the notifications.
Users who has used the app can receive the notifications.
My purpose is to send a notifications with a URL to the user who is not using the app, let him download my app.

I read some posts and know that this may be due to the canvas URL caused.

Here is my code

```
private void sendRequestDialog(Bundle params2) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("to", params2.getString("to"));
    params.putString("message", params2.getString("message"));

    WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(main,
            Session.getActiveSession(), params)).setOnCompleteListener(
            new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            Toast.makeText(main.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(main.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values
                                .getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(main.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(main.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).build();
    requestsDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393651/how-to-send-request-as-notification-to-friend-in-facebook-3-0-android?rq=1   you may have to add user IDS as an array and as you say make sure your app's Canvas URL is implemented correctly

Answer (score 0):

My answer here may help : [How to share a message to facebook -- android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977150/how-to-share-a-message-to-facebook-android/19977711#19977711)

Find the link to the facebook documentation in the comments. Then simply make sure you are following the steps during app creation and specifying a Canvas URL. There are examples at the bottom of the page to assist you. Your code doesn't seem to be the problem, it just needs a suitable link for your application to be able to provide invitations.