# How to share a message to facebook -- android

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

```
     Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("to", useriId);
            params.putString("message","Hello World");
  WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
                JoinVia.this, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                            FacebookException error) {
                        if (error != null) {
                            if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        JoinVia.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        JoinVia.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            final String requestId = values
                                    .getString("request");
                            if (requestId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        JoinVia.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Request sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        JoinVia.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).build();
        requestsDialog.show();
```

This my code to send invitation to friends id. The code can send the notification, but when i click the notification icon from the browser, the invitation is not present. Can anyone guide me how to send a message to friends facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED:

Ignore my previous answer, I misinterpreted the type of dialog that you were trying to produce.

As mentioned in the comments, your code doesn't seem to be the problem since you are successfully getting a notification. Simply follow the steps in the Facebook app creation doc to make sure you are setting your app up correctly, specifying a Canvas URL as shown in the first image to make sure your app can provide invitations properly.

The examples on the same page should provide more help with using the URLs also.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this code is not working, it shows error in facebook dialog. i cant even go inside to the dialog. :(

Comment: So you currently see a dialog but without the "hello world" message?

Comment: Also in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393651/how-to-send-request-as-notification-to-friend-in-facebook-3-0-android?rq=1 they suggest making sure the app you're inviting to has a Canvas url which may help.

Comment: Dude, i'm getting same behavior. I can able to post with friends wall. When i post from device, notification count appears in friends wall, but when i click that notification, i cant see that. Even notification popups message from the sender user name :( don't know where i struck.

Comment: Well if it's getting to the friend I don't think your code is the problem. It's just not finding your app so make sure your app has the right Canvas URL. Also I still don't know what you mean. When they click the notification icon what happens. No dialog shows at all or just no invitation to your app?

Comment: i can get all the dialogs and even i get message that successfully posted. And more importantly i can get the notification count from friends wall. But when we clicks that notification using friends id, the notification disappears. Don't know where the mistake is. Can you please guide me the exact issue. :(

Comment: Are you following all the steps here with your app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/ . Make sure your app has a Canvas URL set ( see the first image).